# emacs does not recognize (require 'semantic-ia)

Tags: semantics, cedet, emacs24

I'm new to emacs, and I'm trying to setup cebet1.1 with emacs 24.1 on Mac. My .emacs is simple:

(load-file "~/elisp/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")

(require ‘semantic-ia)

(global-ede-mode 1)

(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)

(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)

However, when I start emacs, it gives me an error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: ‘semantic-ia". I double checked the cedet installation, and the file ~/elisp/cedet-1.1/semantic/semantic-ia.el does exist.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and the following change works for me

```
   (require 'semantic/ia)
```